# Doubling objects only when rendering

Tags: rendering

I have some glass panes on a temple. In all viewports, including render preview, they are the correct amount. Though when I actually render it, the glass panes triple. Any ideas why this it? Thanks for the help[image: viewport]

[image]

Comment: hmmm, do you have an array modifier that's disabled in viewport but enabled in render per chance?

Comment: I spent hours on this, and that fixed it. I'm dumb. Thank you so so much wilks!!!!!